# Java camel DSL how do I call bean method with multiple expected input types

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am using Java - Camel - DSL implementation

Following code snippet line "no. 3" I am using bean reference to call myMethod with expected input which works pretty well and I like calling pure java way rather then expression based which won't blow until runtime if there is an issue.

How do I call bean method with multiple expected input types.

any help is appreciated.

```
public class MyRoute {

@Autowire
private MyBean myBean;

..

from("my-route"). // 1
.setBody(UUID::new) // 2
.setBody().body(UUID.class, myBean::myMethod) // 3
..

}

@Component
public class MyBean {

public String myMethod(@Body UUID id)
   return "Current id is : "+ id;
}
```